# Can I use javascript library codes inside HTML file instead of referencing it?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, html

Is it possible to copy and paste a javascript library's code inside a HTML file?

I asked because I'm trying to make an app that needs angularjs but due to restrictions at work, I cant reference it to an angularjs file externally regardless if its over the internet or intranet.

I appreciate your help.

Thanks

Comment: You could..yes. Crude,  but you can paste everything in file(s) inside a script tag in the index html file .

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes this is possible but very much not recommended.

This can be done the following way using the `<script>` tag:

```
<body>
    <p>This is HTML bla bla bla...</p>
</body>
<script type="text/javascript">
    //Put your JS code here
</script>
```

Comment: Thanks, Im currently trying it but I keep getting errors, because of commented lines with * or /*

Comment: the comments are being loaded instead of skipping them when I open the hmtl file but I got it working when I used the minified version of angular

Comment: Something was wrong with the comments if they were being loaded and executed. Make sure they are in the following format: `\\Some code`, `/* Some code */`